# Django Rest Framework create Queryset Group By

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, python-3.5

Hello i will write this row sql query:

```
select rating, date, count(rating) as "Count" from analyse
where wkn='x' and date between 'x' and 'y' group by rating
```

My Model Class is this

```
class Analyse(models.Model):
date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
week_day = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=500)
location = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=500)
old_rating = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=500)
rating = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=500)
```

and the Serializer and View is this

```
class RatingSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
rating = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
total = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
date = serializers.DateField()#format='%Y'

class CompaniesChartsView(generics.ListAPIView):
http_method_names = ['get']
permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
serializer_class = RatingSerializer

def get(self, request, wkn, format=None):
    self.query = self.request.GET.get('chart')

    end = datetime.date.today()
    #start = datetime.date(datetime.date.today().year-1, 1, 1)
    start = datetime.date(datetime.date.today().year-1, 
    datetime.date.today().month, datetime.date.today().day)
    try:
        if self.query == "ratings":
            queryset = Analyse.objects.values('date', 'rating') 
                         .filter(
                         Q(wkn=wkn) &
                         Q(date__range=([start, end]))) 
                         .annotate(total=Count('rating'))

            serializer = RatingSerializer(queryset, many=True)

            print(serializer.data)
            print(connection.queries)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response("Bad request", 
              status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    except:
        pass
```

Django generate but this query. This is not that was i will.

```
'SELECT "statistic_app_analyse"."date", 
 "statistic_app_analyse"."rating", 
 COUNT("statistic_app_analyse"."rating") AS "total" FROM 
 "statistic_app_analyse" WHERE ("statistic_app_analyse"."wkn" = 
  \'840400\' AND "statistic_app_analyse"."date" BETWEEN \'2017-12-20\' 
  AND \'2018-12-20\') GROUP BY "statistic_app_analyse"."date", 
  "statistic_app_analyse"."rating"'
```

Django add the date field to group by.

When i change the query to:

```
                      queryset = Analyse.objects.values('rating') 
                         .filter(
                         Q(wkn=wkn) &
                         Q(date__range=([start, end]))) 
                         .annotate(total=Count('rating'))
```

Then works, but the date is missing.

When i change the Django query to a row sql query

```
          queryset = Analyse.objects.raw("SELECT db.wkn, 
          db.rating, db.date, COUNT (*) as 'Count' FROM 
          analyse as db WHERE db.wkn='578580' and db.date like 
          '2018%'")

          queryset = list(queryset)

         serializer = RatingSerializer(queryset, many=True)
         return Response(serializer.data)
```

Then i get an error

```
Internal Server Error: /api/companies/840400/charts/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/hendrik/PycharmProjects/automatic-information-extraction- 
from-stock-analysis/venv/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/home/hendrik/PycharmProjects/automatic-information-extraction- 
from-stock-analysis/venv/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/home/hendrik/PycharmProjects/automatic-information-extraction- 
from-stock-analysis/venv/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, 
**callback_kwargs)
File "/home/hendrik/PycharmProjects/automatic-information-extraction- 
from-stock-analysis/venv/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/hendrik/PycharmProjects/automatic-information-extraction- 
from-stock-analysis/venv/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/hendrik/PycharmProjects/automatic-information-extraction- 
from-stock-analysis/venv/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 497, in dispatch
self.response = self.finalize_response(request, response, *args, 
**kwargs)
File "/home/hendrik/PycharmProjects/automatic-information-extraction- 
from-stock-analysis/venv/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 412, in finalize_response
 % type(response)
 AssertionError: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or 
 HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a 
 <class 'NoneType'>`
 [20/Dec/2018 12:05:18] "GET /api/companies/840400/charts/? 
 chart=ratings 
 HTTP/1.1" 500 85144
```

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your immediate issue is that the view is returning `None` from `get()`. This can be resolved by reworking your try/except.

```
def get(self, request, wkn, format=None):
    self.query = self.request.GET.get('chart')

    end = datetime.date.today()
    #start = datetime.date(datetime.date.today().year-1, 1, 1)
    start = datetime.date(datetime.date.today().year-1, 
    datetime.date.today().month, datetime.date.today().day)
    try:
        if self.query == "ratings":
            queryset = Analyse.objects.values('date', 'rating') 
                         .filter(
                         Q(wkn=wkn) &
                         Q(date__range=([start, end]))) 
                         .annotate(total=Count('rating'))

            serializer = RatingSerializer(queryset, many=True)

            print(serializer.data)
            print(connection.queries)
            return Response(serializer.data)
    except:
        pass
    return Response("Bad request", 
        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

However, catching a blank exception and passing it is a terrible practice. If you're going to pass an exception you should know what possible exception(s) would be raised and at that point you should be catching those specific exceptions instead of simply `Exception`. The other part of it is that it hides what goes wrong with your code. So I'd recommend going with:

```
def get(self, request, wkn, format=None):
    self.query = self.request.GET.get('chart')

    end = datetime.date.today()
    #start = datetime.date(datetime.date.today().year-1, 1, 1)
    start = datetime.date(datetime.date.today().year-1, 
    datetime.date.today().month, datetime.date.today().day)
    if self.query == "ratings":
        queryset = Analyse.objects.values('date', 'rating') 
                     .filter(
                         Q(wkn=wkn) &
                         Q(date__range=([start, end]))) 
                     .annotate(total=Count('rating'))

        serializer = RatingSerializer(queryset, many=True)

        print(serializer.data)
        print(connection.queries)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    return Response("Bad request", 
        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

In order to get the date to get the date removed from the `GROUP BY` clause, try removing it from the argument list to `.values()`:

```
queryset = Analyse.objects.values('rating') 
    .filter(
        Q(wkn=wkn) &
        Q(date__range=([start, end]))) 
    .annotate(total=Count('rating'))
```

Comment: Thank you, but is when i will Show the date as extra Field? Example {Date: xy, Rating: xy, total: 4} ...?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: I mean if I use your query, then the right row sql query does not come ... I get the following query

[{'time': '0.003', 'sql': 'SELECT "statistic_app_analyse"."rating", COUNT("statistic_app_analyse"."rating") AS "total" FROM "statistic_app_analyse" WHERE ("statistic_app_analyse"."wkn" = \'840400\' AND "statistic_app_analyse"."date" BETWEEN \'2017-12-21\' AND \'2018-12-21\') GROUP BY "statistic_app_analyse"."rating"'}]


But i will the following query:



select rating, date, count(rating) as "Count" from analyse
where wkn='x' and date between 'x' and 'y' group by rating

Comment: The difference is that I am missing in the selection column the date